# Electron-builder - how to run a script after/before installing an app

Tags: linux, macos, electron, electron-builder

I have an application written in Electron which uses electron-builder. I want to package the app for Linux (Ubuntu and maybe others too) and Mac. But when the application is installing I also need to run a script used to install some third party software.

For Windows (nsis) I know that there is a configuration: `"include": "installer.nsh"`.

Is there something similar for Linux / Mac that I can use to do this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also asked on GitHub. The answer was:

> For AppImage not possible. For mac DMG not possible.
>
> You can use alternative formats, but I just recommend you to install
>   required software on first run.

Here is the answer: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3436